# Wpf custom geometry scaling

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, pathgeometry

I am working on a very simple game in WPF (I know that wpf is not designed for games, but I do it for fun). I have an `Enemy` class which derives from `CustomControl`. I wrote a piece of code with the template for this control.
here is the code:

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type elements:Enemy}">
                <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding ElementWidth}" Height="                                                       {TemplateBinding ElementHeight}">
                    <Path Fill="LightGoldenrodYellow" >
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="20,20" IsClosed="True">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <LineSegment Point="18, 5"/>
                                        <ArcSegment Point="2,5" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" RotationAngle="90" Size="3,5"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="0,20"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="5,17"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="10,20"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="15,17"/>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="20,20" IsClosed="True">
                                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                                            <LineSegment Point="18, 5"/>
                                            <ArcSegment Point="2,5" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" RotationAngle="90" Size="3,5"/>
                                            <LineSegment Point="0,20"/>
                                            <LineSegment Point="5,17"/>
                                            <LineSegment Point="10,20"/>
                                            <LineSegment Point="15,17"/>
                                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                                <EllipseGeometry Center="6,6" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                                <EllipseGeometry Center="14,6" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                                <EllipseGeometry Center="6,6" RadiusX="1.5" RadiusY="1.5"/>
                                <EllipseGeometry Center="14,6" RadiusX="1.5" RadiusY="1.5"/>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="5,10,10,5" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0"/>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="6,10,2.5,2"/>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="9,13,2.5,2"/>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="12,10,2.5,2"/>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

And now I have a problem, because if I placed my control on a panel, it would have fixed width and height to 20 units (as defined in geometry coordinates above). 
However, I want my shape to be streatched to the place that it recieves in the layout process. So I have tried to put my `Path` element into `Viewbox`, but it still has 20 width and height.

Is there any simple way that solves that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the panel or viewbox that you place the control on has a width and height set to auto?

```
<Viewbox Height="Auto" Width="Auto"></Viewbox>
```